# Magento1.9 shipping method must be specified when admin edit orders

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, sales-order

I am trying to edit order in the admin section when showing "Shipping method must be specified." [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0K6d.png)

[image]

Comment: Any solutions for this error?